# How to make for loop AngularJs with asynchronous function run as blocking function (synchronously)?

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous

I have some code in angularJS like this:

```
$scope.myArray= [{name:"thomas", parentId: 1}, {name:"john", parentId: 2}]
for(var i = 0; i< $scope.myArray.length, i++){
    // I wish this code run as blocking code
    $http.get('getParentById'+$scope.myArray[i].parentId).then(function(result){
        if(result){
            $scope.myArray[i].parentName = result.data;
        }
    });
}
```

My intention very clearly, assigns parentName for each object get by Http request. But the problem is asynchronous in angularJs. I have tried many ways but it can not be fixed. Does anyone have a solution for this?

EDIT: I got an answer in the comment below. The solution is using angular.foreach()

Comment: Start by using a block-scope iterator `i` rather than function scope, or even better, use the Array class method `forEach`.

Comment: Can you explain more clearly? What is using a block-scope iterator i?

Comment: If you are not familiar with block scope, you need to learn that yourself - there are a great number of webpages about it. Here it means that each loop had its own copy of `i` instead of sharing one.

Comment: I have used array foreach as you mentioned and it worked very well. Thank you very much

Comment: Feel free to post your solution as an answer and then accept it after the waiting period

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: @tehhowch There are many duplicates of this question. You have the rep, please vote to close as such.